# Undergraduate Research as an Irregular Student

Tags: research-process, united-states, university, undergraduate

I am currently a Japanese college student. I am going to do research in artificial intelligence from this April.
After completing the first year of research, I am planning to go to the United States for 1 year.

During the last 5-6 months of the plan, I would like to do undergraduate research at some university in the US.
I am not sure if it is possible for an international student to do undergraduate research as an irregular student.
Of course I am not seeking any units or degrees.

How does the system of irregular acceptation of universities work in the US?

Comment: Can you clarify your academic status while in the US? That is, are you just taking a year away from your college, is the visit a sanctioned part of the program, etc?